# is it a proper way to add element id using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i'm willing to do some css changes onmouseover and onmouseout to these divs using javascript.
is it proper way to add unique id to each  element using php like below.

```
<div id="header">
<div id="<?php echo "menu_id".$i++ ?>">home</div>
<div id="<?php echo "menu_id".$i++ ?>">contact</div>
<div id="<?php echo "menu_id".$i++ ?>">about</div>
</div>
```

Comment: By "is it professional?" do you mean "is it considered best practice?" Are you looking for a better way of achieving some task (it's not very clear what the underlying requirement is here), or just for review of your code (of which you haven't provided very much)?

Comment: Why do you need an id to do that? Sometimes adding ids is totally fine. Depends on the situation.

Comment: Pro tip (pun intended) professional means you are getting paid to do something. So if you get paid to do the above it is indeed pretty much professional.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using "only" CSS in this situation is the better option.
Have a look at :nth-child() (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)
and :nth-of-type() (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're dealing with dynamic content so if you need to give all of these unique ID's then this will do it. But what you're trying to achieve based on the image you provide shouldn't require each of these need a unique id though. If you let us know what you need those id's for then we may be able to give a more *professional* way to do it. If they're just css hooks maybe look at the nth-child(n) selector

```
#header div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: rgba(100,100,100,0.4);
}
```

To address the question of professionalism though: professionals have to deal with some pretty funky systems and have to do things to get around those systems' limitations that probably makes their heart hurt a little. If this is one of those situations then congratulations - you're a pro!